# How do I do multithreading in python?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

I got the source code from http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/09/simplistic-python-thread-example/ however when I tried to modify the code to my needs the results are not what I wanted.

```
import time
from threading import Thread


def myfunc():
    time.sleep(2)
    print("thread working on something")

while 1:
    thread = Thread(target=myfunc())
    thread.start()
    print("looping")
```

and got the results of

```
thread working on something
looping
// wait 2 secondd
thread working on something
looping
// wait 2 seconds
thread working on something
looping
// wait 2 seconds and so on
thread working on something
looping
// wait 2 seconds
```

but then I have to wait 2 seconds before I do anything.
I want to be able to do anything while the thread does something else like checking things in an array and compare them.

Comment: You've got an extra set of brackets at `target=myfunc()`. This should be `target=myfunc`. Currently, you are calling `myfunc`, passing the return value (`None`) as the thread function. Warning: If you run with the change, you create an infinite number of threads. You also might want to explain your exact use case more, currently the question is too broad (besides the error).

Comment: @dhke Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the main loop, you are initialising and starting a new thread an endless number of times. In reality you will have millions of threads running. This of course is not practical and would soon crash the program.

The reason your program does not crash is that the function that is running in the thread is executed and ends in the one pass i.e. you do not have a loop in the thread function to keep the thread alive and working.

Suggestion.

Add a loop to your threading function (myfunc) that will continue to run indefinitely in the background.

Initialise and call the thread function outside of the loop in your main section. In this way you will create only 1 thread that will run its own loop in the background. You could of course run a number of these same threads in the background if you called it more than once.

Now create a loop in your main body, and continue with your array checking or any other task that you want to run whilst the threading function continues to run in the background.

Something like this may help

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def myfunc():
    counter = 0
    while 1>0:

        print "The thread counter is at ", counter
        counter += 1
        time.sleep (2)

thread = Thread(target=myfunc)
thread.start()

# The thread has now initialised and is running in the background

mCounter = 0

while 1:

    print "Main loop counter = ", mCounter
    mCounter += 1
    time.sleep (5)
```

In this example, the thread will print a line every 2 seconds, and the main loop will print a line every 5 seconds.

Be careful to close your thread down. In some cases, a keyboard interrupt will stop the main loop, but the thread will keep on running.

I hope this helps.

Comment: no function is running in background threads. `myfunc()` is running in the main thread. The issue: `target=myfunc()` vs. `target=myfunc` (no parentheses).